# pgAdmin 4 Migrate server list from pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

How to migrate/import Server list with login info in pgAdmin 4 from pgAdmin III.
In pgAdmin III installations that was done with migrating pgadmin registry keys with regedit, but as I see new pgAdmin has different registry structure in different location (doesn't use old registry path as pgAdmin3 used).

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid right now that's not possible, pgAdmin4 will automatically locate all local Postgres installations but for remote server(s) you have to add it manually.

Comment: I am not sure why it is hard for pgAdmin to make migration script/procedure on upgrade or something like that???